# ITextSharp returning Null when converting to IDictionary or ICollection

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've inherited an application with an older version of ITextSharp (4.1.2.0). When parsing a PDF, these 2 lines of code will return null which is not supposed to happen. What's up with the conversions? Or is it a PDF formatting issue?

```
ICollection<string> fieldNames = (pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys) as ICollection<string>;

IDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item> fieldValues = (pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields) as IDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "as" operator returns null, if an *implicit* conversion cannot be performed.

Have a look at the definitions for Keys and Fields (right-click / "Go to Definition") in Visual Studio.

Perhaps their types cannot be converted to the datatypes in your code? You may need to change them eg.

```
 IEnumerable<string> fieldNames = (pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys) as IEnumerable<string>;
```